# How to use autolayout to allot full frame to topview when bottom view is hidden

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have two UIViews aligned vertically in Main view, there is business logic like if usertype A is logined need to show both views, If usertype B logined need to show top view only and hide that bottom view but topview should get total frame of bottom view aswell, Can anyone please suggest me how can implement with Autolayout ?.

Answer (score 0):

You should define height constraint for your bottom view.

Main idea is to change that constraint for your purpose. Just create outlet for height in your code and set it constant to 0, when you need to hide it (optionally, set hidden property to YES, if you wish)

Storyboard steps:

1. Add leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints for top view
   [image]
2. Add leading, trailing, **height** and bottom constraints for bottom view
   [image]
3. Your constraints should look like:
   [image]

Last step - drag outlet for height to your view controller in order to get access to change it's constant

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please provide me any sample code kind of thing for setting height constraint constant setting, I did like below but still unable to get                               self.bottomViewHeightConstraint.constant = 100;
        [self.bottomView .addConstraint(self.bottomViewHeightConstraint)];
        [self.bottomView .updateConstraints()];

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target is iOS 9 or later, the easiest way to do this is to put the views in a `UIStackView`:

[image: demo with stack view]

I put the two views (plus the toolbar) in a vertical stack view. I constrained each view's leading and trailing edges to the stack view, and constrained the top and bottom views to have equal heights. Then I set the priority of the equal-height constraint to 249 (a fairly low priority). If you don't want equal heights, you can set whatever height constraints you want for when both views are visible. Just set them to a low priority so the stack view can override them when only one view is showing.

Hiding and showing the views is easy, even with animation. It's this simple:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)hideTop:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.topView.hidden = YES;
        self.bottomView.hidden = NO;
    }];
}

- (IBAction)hideBottom:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.bottomView.hidden = YES;
        self.topView.hidden = NO;
    }];
}

- (IBAction)showAll:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.topView.hidden = NO;
        self.bottomView.hidden = NO;
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to support iOS8 aswell , is there any alternate way Rob